# How to do a 4-d array transpose defined as such in numpy

Tags: arrays, numpy, convolution

suppose we have a 4-d matrix of shape (A,B,C,D), f. And we want to make such a transpose where we have  f_transpose(i,j,k,c) = f(A-i+1,B-j+1,c,k). This is related to backpropagation of convnet, applying conv operator to get the gradient of conv layer. Can any one help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to reverse the first two axes and switch the last two. Reversing an axis can be done with a `::-1` slice, and switching axes is [`numpy.swapaxes`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html):

```
g = numpy.swapaxes(f, 2, 3)[::-1, ::-1]
```

Comment: One more question though, what if I want to move the first dimension to be between the third and the fourth dimension? Do I need to use swapaxes two times or are there any one liner solution?

Comment: @jack I am guessing that would be : `np.transpose(f,(1,2,0,3))`.

Comment: @Divakar Thanks! And I found that np.rollaxis would also work.